# How to fill a QComboBox with elements from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a combobox on a QTDesigner QDialog form that I would like to fill with a the contents of a column in a CSV file. I invoke the call for the combo box and have the function built to pull the values from the CSV, but the combo box will not update with the information.

```
self.optStates.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectState)
def selectState(self):
    with open('States.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile, delimiter=',')
        states = []
        states.extend([row['state'] for row in csvReader if row['state']])
```

The other code has been omitted, but the rest of the dialog works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`currentIndexChanged` is a signal that is triggered when you choose an option of the `QComboBox` and since there is no item in your `QComboBox` it will never fire, besides there is no need to use it in this case. What you must do is fill it in the constructor using the `addItems()` method

```
def __init__(self, another_arguments):
    # 
    # some code
    # 
    with open('States.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile, delimiter=',')
        states = [row['state'] for row in csvReader if row['state']]
        self.optStates.addItems(states)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. For some reason I had in it in a pyqtSlot() as well and needed to put it in the main __init__. Works like a champ now.